# Is there a software which can compare printer color profiles (not only gamma but color mapping)

Tags: printing, color-management, color-correction

I have a Canon Pro 10s Photo Printer and recently printed some photos on the Canon Plus Semi-gloss (SG-201) paper using the printer profiles included with the driver (my screen is calibrated using a Spyder 5/DispCal Gui). The prints came out really dark with low saturation. I printed from DxO Photo Lab 5, and tried both color management by driver and by application.

I then created a printer profile with SpyderPrint, and the print was fine. I wanted to find out how the profiles differ (the one supplied by Canon and the one I created). But I could only find software comparing the gamut of profiles - which is not really conclusive.

Is there a software capable of giving a more comprehensive comparison of printer profiles?

Comment: Maybe duplicate of https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/75784/is-there-free-software-to-compare-gamuts

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is print a calibration test chart using each profile. Then scan them back into the computer (or photograph them). Then use a digital color meter/color picker to select the individual test blocks/colors and see how they differ in the L*a*b*, HSL, RGB color spaces. I think you could use DXO Photolabs ColorWheel tool to do this.

This does add the secondary color interpretation of the scanner/camera; but it should be consistent for both. Without printing specific colors and seeing how they differ, the only thing that can be stated is the gamut (possible colors). There is an [ICC Profile Inspector](https://www.color.org/profileinspector.xalter) (Windows), but the information would be meaningless to most... you would need a deep level of knowledge/understanding of the [ICC profile standard](https://chrome-extension://bdfcnmeidppjeaggnmidamkiddifkdib/viewer.html?file=https://www.color.org/icc32.pdf).